# How to add new action in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii

We have this PHP application already NOT using any framework. We are taping into Yii framework for building webservices for our simple mobile app. We are quite new to Yii framework.

We follow this article and managed to get to work - http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/#hh13

Mainly it just created **ApiController.php** and extended the Controller class.

We have 3 tables in databases: Category, Subcategory, Ad. 
The table relation as follow:

> 1. Category has many Subcategory
> 2. Subcategory has many Ad

At the moment by default after doing CRUD process, it generates the codes for Category, Subcategory and Ad. The issue that we have that this codes generates for actionList as select entire records.

Here's the view for our simple mobile app as follow:

> 1. Display Categories as a listview
> 2. Once the category clicked, then display SubCategories as a listview
> 3. Once the subcategory clicked, then display Ads as listview
> 4. Once the ads clicked, then display the Ad as detail

Looking the point 2-4 above, how do we modify this ApiController that we have to do the following below?

> - List SubCategory by CategoryID
> - List Ad by SubCategoryID

Here's the **actionList** of **ApiController.php** that we've created based on the article above:

```
// {{{ actionList
    public function actionList()
    {
        // $this->_checkAuth();

        switch($_GET['model'])
        {
            case 'category': // {{{ 
                $models = Category::model()->findAll();
                break; // }}} 
            case 'ad': // {{{ 
                $models = Ad::model()->findAll();
                break; // }}} 
            case 'subcategory': // {{{ 
                $models = Subcategory::model()->findAll();
                break; // }}}       
            default: // {{{ 
                $this->_sendResponse(501, sprintf('Error: Mode <b>list</b> is not implemented for model <b>%s</b>',$_GET['model']) );
                exit; // }}} 
        }
        if(is_null($models)) {
            $this->_sendResponse(200, sprintf('No items where found for model <b>%s</b>', $_GET['model']) );
        } else {
            $rows = array();
            foreach($models as $model)
                $rows[] = $model->attributes;

            $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($rows));
        }
    } // }}}
```

I'm appreciated your help.

Comment: **Side note**: Don't use constructs like `$this->_checkAuth()` in (each) action, use [action filters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) for this

Comment: Thanks PeterM - will do. BTW ... any answer to my question ?

Comment: I would use Gii to automatically create template code and copy those examples. `http://localhost/web/gii`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate subcategories as follows (name variables as in your generated code). $category is the loaded model for which you will display subcategories for.

```
foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
{
    // you have your subcategory 
}
```

Similarly, you can iterate ads the same way:

```
foreach($subcategory->ads as $ad)
{
     // you have all ads under this subcategory
}
```

You can put the second code inside first to have all of them.

This can be in view or controller, it depends on how you want to display...

Comment: Thanks @Malkocglu. I've added a sample code so you can have a look.